# Django test cases based on base test case

Tags: python, django

In my webapp I have a ListItem class and then many other classes based upon this but with different names.

I have separate test modules for all of these currently. This means theres alot of repeating test code.

I'm trying to create a BaseListItemTestCase Class which has a variable `self.listitem_model` set, uses that on all its tests. Meaning the code is not repeated.

The `self.listitem_model` would be set in a child test case containing just an **init**() method to set this.

I did all of the above, the issue is, if theres 1 test within the Base test class and I only ran the child test case, the test runs twice.

Is there a reason for this? I just want the test I told to run, to run.

```
class BaseListItemTestCase(APITestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseListItemTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listitem_model = None

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.listitem_model.objects.all().count(), 0)

class LikeListTestCase(BaseListItemTestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LikeListTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listitem_model = LikeListItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You've put the test method into the base class, so it's inherited by the child class. Now there are two classes with a `test_something` method, so both will be run.

Put the test in the child class. Or if you want the logic to be in the base class, put it in a method that doesn't belong with `test_`, and have a basic `test_something` method in the child class that simply calls that method.